# Windows Phone change CameraType

Tags: asynchronous, camera, windows-phone

I'm trying to change the CameraType (FrontFacing/Primary) of my Camera in my app.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Canvas x:Name="viewfinderCanvas" Width="720" Height="480" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" >

        <!--Camera viewfinder -->
        <Canvas.Background>
            <VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush" />
        </Canvas.Background>

        <!-- Brackets for Touch Focus -->
        <TextBlock 
            x:Name="focusBrackets" 
            Text="[   ]" 
            FontSize="40"
            Visibility="Collapsed"/>

    </Canvas>

    <!--Button StackPanel to the right of viewfinder>-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" >
        <Button Content="Front" Name="btCameraType" Click="changeFacing_Clicked" FontSize="26" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Height="75"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--Used for debugging >-->
    <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,428,0,0" Name="txtDebug" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="626" FontSize="24" FontWeight="ExtraBold" />
</Grid>
```

And this is the Code Behind:

```
private void changeFacing_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cam.CameraType == CameraType.FrontFacing)
        cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
    else
        cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.FrontFacing);
    viewfinderBrush.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
    {
        viewfinderBrush.SetSource(cam);
    });
}
```

So I'm actually just changing the CameraType when the user clicks on a button. The problem is that when the user clicks several times on the button (so like 5 times in 2 seconds), the program can't handle it and it stops working... Any solution on how to avoid this problem?

I've also tried en-/disabling the button, but I still can click on the button..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that when the user clicks several times on the button
>   (so like 5 times in 2 seconds), the program can't handle it and it
>   stops working

In my experience, I've noticed that the `PhotoCamera` class has a tendency of throwing a lot of exception, sometimes for obscure reasons.

I might get some downvotes but here is what I would do: put the code in a `try...catch` block, like so:

```
try
{
    if (cam.CameraType == CameraType.FrontFacing)
        cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
    else
        cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.FrontFacing);
    viewfinderBrush.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
    {
        viewfinderBrush.SetSource(cam);
    });
}
catch (Exception) { }
```

Of course, before using the FrontFacing camera, you need to check if the device has one:

```
PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.FrontFacing)
```

**EDIT** :
Based on the comments, the `try..catch` method is not enough.
Here is an even uglier solution that should work:

```
DateTime lastChange = DateTime.MinValue;
private void changeFacing_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - lastChange;
    if (elapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds < 2000) // If the last change occured less than 2 seconds ago, ignore it
        return;

    if (cam.CameraType == CameraType.FrontFacing)
        cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
    else
        cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.FrontFacing);

    viewfinderBrush.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
    {
        viewfinderBrush.SetSource(cam);
    });

    lastChange = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: I've also thought about try - catch, but it's the same result. Clicking on the button (to change the CameraType) a lot of times will freeze the app. There's no exception, no "debug error".... nothing. It just freezes/stops working (but the app is still open) and Visual Studio also gives no error or sees that the app is frozen, so I have to stop the app manually by clicking on "Stop Debugging". --- This actually happens when I click on the Button when the new CameraType hasn't been set.

Comment: Wow...in that case, an even uglier solution would be to check if the last change wasn't made X seconds before.

Comment: yes, that would be one "ugly" solution... :/ ... I've also tried to used System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500) at `finally{}`, but the CameraType changes AFTER the sleep?... Don't get it. Anyway, I'll try to use the method with checking X seconds or probably just use Primary camera, if it doesn't work...

Comment: @Rudi I've noticed similar behavior, but only with the debugger attached. Never in the final application. Try to deploy the application on a device, launch it manually (without the debugger), and see if you can reproduce the issue. If you can't, don't bother searching for a fix.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how I would do, tell me if it works.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer... @KooKiz the solution with the 2 second timer is working, but the problem is sometimes occurring when I've the debugger attached (like you've said..). So I'll test the final application on the phone and see if it it crashes, but at the moment it's working normally.

Comment: @OlivierPayen Thanks for helping me :) It's not really the solution I expected or the reason why it's not working, but it's a solution to avoid this problem.